# Unable to find image in recent option in file manager [Android 10, Android 11] [react-native-photo-editor]

Tags: android, react-native, android-image, photoeditorsdk

I'm using react-native-photo-editor[https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor] npm
I'm testing on both Andoird 10 & Android 11 devices.

```
Scenario:
When I click on the save option after editing. Then the image is saved into Pictures/PhotoEditorSDK/ folder.
```

After that, the Image is visible when I go into the PhotoEditorSDK folder using internal memory. i.e., [internal storage / Pictures / PhtotoEditorSDK ]

In File Manager, We have some shortcuts to display data.
Like in my redmi device, I have `Images, Downloads or recent, etc` shortcuts in the file manager.
That edited image is not present in recent or Images shortcuts.

That edited image that is present in the Internal Storage path will be visible in images after some time [Like 1 day].

Can anyone tell, what's happening here?

Comment: So you are able to locate the image. Then why that subject?

Comment: But, I am unable to get that image in resolver.query.
Also image is not present in Image side menu option at a time

Comment: Then you have to change the subject. And also explain what you mean with an Image side menu option as i have no idea.

Comment: `will be visible in images after some time` ? No idea what you mean with `images`.